# Setting EndDate based on StartDate in next list item in a C# List

Tags: c#, linq

I have a C# list items as follows-

```
List<MyClass> All_Items = GetListItems();
```

`GetListItems()` returns the result as follows-

```
Category    StartDate    EndDate
AA          2008-05-1    
AA          2012-02-1
BB          2009-09-1
BB          2010-08-1
CC          2009-10-1
```

Using LINQ on `All_Items`, I want to update EndDate column in a way that if

1. If the current Category's StartDate is less than the Start Date of next bigger date item within same Category then use one less day than that of bigger date.
2. If there is no bigger date remaining then update to 2099-12-31

Final result is as follows-

```
Category    StartDate    EndDate
AA          2008-05-1    2012-01-31
AA          2012-02-1    2099-12-31
BB          2009-09-1    2010-07-31
BB          2010-08-1    2099-12-31
CC          2009-10-1    2099-12-31
```

I can only think of getting it done using too many loops. What is the better option?

Comment: The start date of the fourth row is different between the "before" and "after"

Comment: Do you have any particular criteria for which of the "bigger dates" in the Category you take?

Comment: and what is next bigger? next bigger by current items order, or minimum from bigger dates in the same category?

Comment: its minimum from bigger dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. It Loops over all items and selects the next bigger item.StartDate for the same category.
If such an item is not available it sets you default date.

I couldn't Test the code as I'm writing on my mobile, so any correction is welcome.

```
foreach(var item in All_Items)
{
    var nextItem = (from i in All_Items 
                          where i != null && 
                                      i.Category == item.Category &&
                                      i.StartDate > item.StartDate
                          orderby i.StartDate
                          select i).FirstOrDefault();
   item.EndDate = nextItem != null ? nextItem.StartDate.AddDays(-1) : new DateTime(2099,12,31);
}
```

Comment: This is the simplest!! However there is some syntax problem (Coz you worked on mobile!!)

Answer (score 2):

You can select dates for each category and put it into dictionary to save time later.

Then you just go through all your items and check if the start date less than next in category or not, according to you requirements.

Here it is:

```
        var categoryDictionary = All_Items
                                    .GroupBy(i => i.Category)
                                    .ToDictionary(
                                        g => g.Key, 
                                        g => g.Select(i => i.StartDate));
        var defaultDate = DateTime.Parse("2099-12-31");
        foreach (var item in All_Items)
        {
            var nextDateInCategory = categoryDictionary[item.Category]
                                        .Where(i => i > item.StartDate)
                                        .OrderBy(i => i)
                                        .FirstOrDefault();
            item.EndDate =
                nextDateInCategory != default(DateTime)
                    ? nextDateInCategory.AddDays(-1) 
                    : defaultDate;
        }
```

Comment: I think you are decreasing 1 day from the biggest date in current Category. But we need to decrease one day from the next bigger date in current Category

Comment: hmm..thanks.. didn't notice it..Just updated my question

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is not good for processing dependencies between elements of a sequence, and for sure is not intended for updating.

Here is the simple and efficient way to achieve the goal:

```
var groups = All_Items.OrderBy(item => item.StartDate).GroupBy(item => item.Category);
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    MyClass last = null;
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        if (last != null) last.EndDate = item.StartDate.AddDays(-1);
        last = item;
    }
    last.EndDate = new DateTime(2099, 12, 31);
}
```

So we use LINQ just to order the elements by `StartDate` and group the result by `Category` (which preserves the ordering inside each group). Then simply iterate the LINQ query result and update the `EndDate` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your `MyClass` looks something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Here is how you can do it, see the comments in the code for an explanation.

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> All_Items = new List<MyClass>
{
    new MyClass { Category = "AA", StartDate = new DateTime(2008, 5, 1) },
    new MyClass { Category = "AA", StartDate = new DateTime(2012, 2, 1) },
    new MyClass { Category = "BB", StartDate = new DateTime(2009, 9, 1) },
    new MyClass { Category = "BB", StartDate = new DateTime(2010, 8, 1) },
    new MyClass { Category = "CC", StartDate = new DateTime(2009, 10, 1) }
}
    // Group by category
    .GroupBy(c => c.Category)
    // Colapse the groups into a single IEnumerable
    .SelectMany(g => 
    {
        // Store the already used dates
        List<DateTime> usedDates = new List<DateTime>();

        // Get a new MyClass that has the EndDate set, from each MyClass in the category
        return g.Select(c => 
        {
            // Get all biggerDates that were not used already
            var biggerDates = g.Where(gc => gc.StartDate > c.StartDate && !usedDates.Any(ud => ud == gc.StartDate));
            // Set the endDate to the default one
            DateTime date = new DateTime(2099, 12, 31);

            // If a bigger date was found, mark it as used and set the EndDate to it
            if (biggerDates.Any()) {
                date = biggerDates.Min(gc => gc.StartDate).AddDays(-1);
                usedDates.Add(date);
            }

            return new MyClass
            {
                Category = c.Category,
                StartDate = c.StartDate,
                EndDate = date
            };
        });
    });
```

Comment: Why first bigger date?

Comment: but according to author's comment on my answer that was exactly what he wanted, so put it back :)

Answer (score 1):

In a single LINQ statement (`maxEndDate` is 2099-12-31):

```
All_Items.GroupBy(category => category.Category).Select(key =>
                {
                    var maxCategoryStartDate = key.Max(value => value.StartDate);
                    return key.Select(v => {
                        if (DateTime.Equals(v.StartDate, maxCategoryStartDate))
                        {
                            v.EndDate = maxEndDate;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            v.EndDate = maxCategoryStartDate - TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                        }
                        return v;
                        });
                }
            ).SelectMany(x => x);
```